# I am trying gzip compression for my javascripts and css file but for css it is not working

Tags: gzip, compression

I am trying gzip compression for my js and css files. but for css it is not working. also when i do page speed analysis using firefox page speed it asks to enable gzip compression on your server. it means gzip compression is not working.

Here is the php code which i am using at the top of each php file

```
if (substr_count($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip')) ob_start("ob_gzhandler"); else ob_start();
```

and here is the .htaccess code for gzip compression

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
# Insert filter on all content
###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
# Insert filter on selected content types only
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

# Netscape 4.x has some problems...
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

# Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

# MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

# Don't compress images
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

# Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/png
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/gif
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/jpg
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/jpeg
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/vnd.microsoft.icon
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

# Or, compress certain file types by extension:
<Files *.html>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</Files>
```

can anyone help me? my website url is http://www.pricecatalogs.com/

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain the MIME type for CSS files is being set?

```
AddType text/css .css
```

Answer (score 0):

in your HTML you should have type="text/css" when you include css files:

`<link type="text/" href="style.css" ... />`